# How do I instantiate a Queue object in java?

Tags: java, data-structures, queue

When I try:

```
Queue<Integer> q = new Queue<Integer>();
```

The compiler is giving me an error. Any help?

Also, if I want to initialize a queue do I have to implement the methods of the queue?

Comment: Do you need the queue to be thread safe?

Comment: `Queue` is an interface. http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/HashSet.java#HashSet.add%28java.lang.Object%29

Comment: @roottraveller Link doesn't work any more. And if someone ask to _instantiate_ an interface that person is usually looking for the names of the concrete classes implementing that interface.

Answer (score 167, accepted):

A `Queue` is an interface, which means you cannot construct a `Queue` directly.

The best option is to construct off a class that already implements the `Queue` interface, like one of the following: `AbstractQueue`, `ArrayBlockingQueue`, `ArrayDeque`, `ConcurrentLinkedQueue`, `DelayQueue`, `LinkedBlockingQueue`, `LinkedList`, `PriorityBlockingQueue`, `PriorityQueue`, or `SynchronousQueue`.

An alternative is to write your own class which implements the necessary Queue interface.  It is not needed except in those rare cases where you wish to do something special while providing the rest of your program with a `Queue`.

```
public class MyQueue<T extends Tree> implements Queue<T> {
   public T element() {
     ... your code to return an element goes here ...
   }

   public boolean offer(T element) {
     ... your code to accept a submission offer goes here ...
   }

   ... etc ...
}
```

An even less used alternative is to construct an anonymous class that implements `Queue`.  You probably don't want to do this, but it's listed as an option for the sake of covering all the bases.

```
new Queue<Tree>() {
   public Tree element() {
     ...
   };

   public boolean offer(Tree element) {
     ...
   };
   ...
};
```

Comment: Oh dear... I fear someone reading this will use an anonymous `Queue`... but +1 anyways.

Comment: Actually, Jon's is more clear. I will +1 this if you update it to mention concurrency and get rid of the code for anonymous classes... I think it makes the answer more confusing for someone that wants to know what to do because they almost surely don't want to do that. (Even if they wanted their own class, there is no need to make it anonymous)

Comment: @Tom didn't take out the anonymous class info as it's good to know it is possible, but I put in the "Write your own implementation" before it which distances it further from the first listed (more common) alternatives.

Comment: Why not mention `ArrayDeque`

Comment: I am not able to find enqueue() method in any of the classes you mentioned, I am only able to find add() method, please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 174):

[`Queue`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) is an interface. You can't instantiate an interface directly except via an anonymous inner class. Typically this *isn't* what you want to do for a collection. Instead, choose an existing implementation. For example:

```
Queue<Integer> q = new LinkedList<Integer>();
```

or

```
Queue<Integer> q = new ArrayDeque<Integer>();
```

Typically you pick a collection implementation by the performance and concurrency characteristics you're interested in.

Comment: From [ArrayDeque](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html): "This class is likely to be faster than Stack when used as a stack, and faster than LinkedList when used as a queue". It's due to CPU-cache-friendly data locality and less frequent allocations.

Answer (score 44):

```
Queue<String> qe=new LinkedList<String>();

qe.add("b");
qe.add("a");
qe.add("c");
```

Since [`Queue`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) is an interface, you can't create an instance of it as you illustrated

Comment: `java.util.Queue` is an interface. You can't instantiate interfaces. You need to create an instance of a class implementing that interface. In this case a LinkedList is such a class.

Comment: @Tod yes was on the way .. :)

Comment: Thanks @JigarJoshi!! is there any way to do same thing with stack? I couldn't find anything.

Comment: @Zeh `Stack<String> stack = new Stack<>();   stack.push("a"); stack.push("b"); System.out.println(stack.pop());` 

`import java.util.Stack;`

Answer (score 17):

Queue is an interface; you can't explicitly construct a Queue. You'll have to instantiate one of its implementing classes. Something like:

```
Queue linkedList = new LinkedList();
```

[Here's a link to the Java tutorial on this subject.](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html)

Comment: this is not working anymore..! Although this declaration is working --> Queue<Character> queue=new ArrayDeque<Character>();

Comment: @MdFaisal Works fine for me w/ java version "1.7.0_71"

Answer (score 15):

[image]

The Queue interface extends java.util.Collection with additional insertion, extraction, and inspection operations like:

`+offer(element: E):` boolean // **Inserting an element**

`+poll(): E`  // **Retrieves the element and returns NULL if queue is empty**

`+remove(): E` // **Retrieves and removes the element and throws an Exception if queue is empty**

`+peek(): E` // **Retrieves,but does not remove, the head of this queue, returning null if this queue is empty.**

`+element(): E` // **Retrieves, but does not remove, the head of this queue, throws an exception if te queue is empty.**

Example Code for implementing Queue:

```
java.util.Queue<String> queue = new LinkedList<>();
queue.offer("Hello");
queue.offer("StackOverFlow");
queue.offer("User");

System.out.println(queue.peek());

while (queue.size() > 0){
    System.out.println(queue.remove() + " ");
}
//Since Queue is empty now so this will return NULL
System.out.println(queue.peek());
```

Output Of the code :

```
Hello
Hello 
StackOverFlow 
User 
null
```

Comment: Best answer. Deserves more upvotes.

Answer (score 8):

[Queue in Java](https://web.archive.org/web/20180508024116/http://singletonjava.blogspot.com:80/2016/03/java-queue-example.html) is defined as an interface and many ready-to-use implementation is present as part of JDK release.
Here are some:
[LinkedList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html), Priority Queue, ArrayBlockingQueue, ConcurrentLinkedQueue, Linked Transfer Queue, [Synchronous Queue](https://web.archive.org/web/20170830095206/http://singletonjava.blogspot.com/2016/02/java-synchronousqueue-synchronous-queue.html) etc.

SO You can create any of these class and hold it as Queue reference. for example

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;

public class QueueExample {

 public static void main (String[] args) {
  Queue que = new LinkedList();
  que.add("first");
  que.offer("second");
  que.offer("third");
  System.out.println("Queue Print:: " + que);
  
  String head = que.element();
  System.out.println("Head element:: " + head);
  
  String element1 = que.poll();
  System.out.println("Removed Element:: " + element1);
  
  System.out.println("Queue Print after poll:: " + que);
  String element2 = que.remove();
  System.out.println("Removed Element:: " + element2);
  
  System.out.println("Queue Print after remove:: " + que);  
 }
}
```

You can also implement your own custom Queue implementing Queue interface.

Answer (score 7):

Queue is an interface in java, you can not do that.

Instead you have two options:

option1:

```
Queue<Integer> Q = new LinkedList<>();
```

option2:

```
Queue<Integer> Q = new ArrayDeque<>();
```

I recommend using option2 as it is bit faster than the other

Answer (score 5):

`Queue` is an interface in java, you could not do that.
try:

```
Queue<Integer> Q = new LinkedList<Integer>();
```