# NullPointerException in Queue

Tags: java, queue

I implemented some code involving queues and while running it I get a NullPointerException.Please help me to fix it.I am only writing the shorter form of that code.

```
import java.util.*;
class ex
{
public static void main(String args[])throws IOException
{

    Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
    int i;
    String s;
    int n=in.nextInt();

    Queue<Integer> q=null;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        q.add(i);//I get the error in this line
    }
    System.out.println(q.size());
} 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to initialize the queue first:

```
Queue<Integer> q=null;
```

Should be:

```
Queue<Integer> q = new Queue<Integer>();
```

The reason for the error is that you are trying to add values to q. q is only set to be of the type `Queue<Integer>` and not to be a reference to an object of that type itself.

Comment: You can't instantiate `Queue` as the class is abstract

Answer (score 2):

You get an NPE because `q` is `null`.

You have to create an object before you can use it, for example:

```
Queue<Integer> q = new LinkedList<Integer>();
```

Here, I've picked `LinkedList` as a class implementing the `Queue` interface. There are lots of others: see the "All Known Implementing Classes" section of the [`Queue` javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html).

Answer (score 1):

```
Queue<Integer> q = null;
```

Well ... that's `null` and:

```
 q.add(i);
```

There you're trying to use it. Ergo, Exception.

You have to *instantiate* the object in order to have one that you can use:

```
Queue<Integer> q = new Queue<Integer>();
```

If this wasn't a simple typo / oversight, you may want to start at the beginning of the java tutorials provided by Oracle or get a "Learning java" type book before tackling something more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

```
Queue<Integer> q=null;
...
q.add(i);//I get the error in this line
```

Your `Queue` reference is `null`, so you get a `NullPointerException` when trying to access it. Before using it, `q` has to point to something valid like for example:

```
Queue<Integer> q = new Queue<Integer>();
```

Answer (score 0):

That happens because `q` is `null`. You need to initialize it with something before you can use it, for example:

```
 Queue<Integer> q = new AbstractQueue<Integer>();
```

**For some details and samples see:**

- [How do I instantiate a Queue object in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4626812/how-do-i-instantiate-a-queue-object-in-java/4626830#4626830)
- http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/queue.html
- http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize q

```
Queue<Integer> q = new AbstractQueue<Integer>();
```