# Netflix style java program

Tags: java, queue, netflix

So I was given the task to create a very simple Netflix based program. So essentially it has to have a few different classes. A movie class (with basic movie info, already done this though) and a user class (this has to have basic user info like name and account number. but also must have a movie list that displays the five most recently watched movies, and a playlist or essentially a Queue that has the next movies they are going to watch) This is where I am stuck currently, because I do not know enough about Queues to make one for this project. So how would I go about creating a queue for this?

Comment: See [How do I instantiate a Queue object in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4626812/how-do-i-instantiate-a-queue-object-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

A `Queue` is a [first in, first out (FIFO)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFO) data structure.  You can just add objects of your `Movie` class to the `Queue` and retrieve them as you want.  Check out the [Queue API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html).

Also, here is [the Oracle/Sun tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/queue.html) for using Queues.

Answer (score 0):

A Queue is a data structure that uses the FIFO format. In the Java API a Queue is an interface which you can either implement yourself, or use an object such as a LinkedList which does it for you. Here is some sample code which should show you one way to use an ArrayDeque as a Queue.

```
import java.util.ArrayDeque;
import java.util.Queue;


public class QueueTest {

    public static void main(String args[]){

        Queue myQ = new ArrayDeque();

        myQ.add("movie one");
        myQ.add("movie two");
        myQ.add("movie three");

        while(myQ.peek() != null){
            //Movies will be printed in the order they were inserted
            System.out.println(myQ.remove());
        }
    }
}
```