# Enqueue, Dequeue and ViewQueue in Java

Tags: java, queue

I am doing a queue in java. Here is my code:

```
public class ListQueue {
public static void main(String[] args){
    Queue myQueue;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input;
    int choice = 99;
    do{
        System.out.println("================");
        System.out.println("Queue Operations Menu");
        System.out.println("================");
        System.out.println("1,Enquene");
        System.out.println("2,Dequeue");
        System.out.println("3,Empty?");
        System.out.println("4,Count?");
        System.out.println("5,View Queue");
        System.out.println("0, Quit\n");
        System.out.println("Enter Choice:");
        try{
            choice = sc.nextInt();
            switch(choice){
            case 1:
                System.out.println("Please enter name: ");
                input = sc.next();
                myQueue.enqueue(input);
                System.out.println(input + "is successful queued");
                break;
            case 2:
                if(myQueue.isEmpty()){

                }
                break;
            case 3:
                if(myQueue.isEmpty()){
                    System.out.println("Queue is empty");
                }else{
                    System.out.println("Queue is not empty");
                }
                break;
            case 4:
                System.out.println("Number of people is " + "the queue" + myQueue.size());
                break;
            case 5:
                if(!myQueue.isEmpty())
                    myQueue.viewQueue();
                else
                    System.out.println("Queue is empty");
                break;
            case 0:
                System.out.println("Good-bye");
                break;
            default:
                    System.out.println("Invalid choice");
            }
        }
        catch(InputMismatchException e){
            System.out.println("Please enter 1-5, 0 to quit");
            sc.nextLine();
        }
    }while(choice != 0);
}
```

}

However, I have error at the enqueue() and viewQueue() which I wonder why. Am I declare the queue in a wrong way? Thanks in advance. I am new to queue so please bear with me.

Answer (score 13):

Java queues don't have enqueue and dequeue methods, these operations are done using the following methods:

Enqueuing:

- `add(e)`: throws exception if it fails to insert the object
- `offer(e)`: returns false if it fails to insert the object

Dequeuing:

- `remove()`: throws exception if the queue is empty
- `poll()`: returns null if the queue is empty

Take a look to the first object in the queue:

- `element()`: throws exception if the queue is empty
- `peek()`: returns null if the queue is empty

> The add method, which Queue inherits from Collection, inserts an
>   element unless it would violate the queue's capacity restrictions, in
>   which case it throws `IllegalStateException`. The offer method, which is
>   intended solely for use on bounded queues, differs from add only in
>   that it indicates failure to insert an element by returning false.

(see: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/queue.html)

You can also check this as this is more useful:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a96587/apexampl.htm

Comment: By the way how do I loop thru the element inside queue? Can you post me some example

Answer (score 3):

You have not initialized myQueue:

```
Queue myQueue;
```

Note that Queue is an abtract class,you need initialize myQueue to the appropriate implementation.

Refer below javaDoc:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html

Answer (score 1):

@By the way how do I loop thru the element inside queue? Can you post me some example –

I have just added functionality in your Case 5: which is for viewing the List elements.

```
case 5:
    if(!myQueue.isEmpty())
    {
    for(Iterator it=myQueue.iterator();it.hasNext();)
        System.out.println(it.next());
//or using as a Object in Enhanced for loop
        //for (Object element : myQueue)
        //System.out.println(element);
    }
    else
        System.out.println("Queue is empty");
    break;
```

And as Ryman Holmes suggested you can use ArayDeque.

```
Queue<String> myQueue = new ArrayDeque<String>();
```

**Benefits:**
 - It is faster than Stack and LinkedList
 - ArrayDeque have no capacity restrictions so they can grow as necessary to support usage.

**Risk:**
 - They are not thread-safe; in the absence of external synchronization.
 - They do not support concurrent access by multiple threads.

Answer (score 0):

Like zerocool said you are not initializing the Queue, as Queue is an interface and you cannot instantiate an interface directly, you need to instantiate a class that implements the interface `Queue` such as `ArrayDequeue`, `LinkedList` etc...

To initialise the Queue and get rid of the errors you need something like this:

```
Queue<Integer> myQueue = new ArrayDeque<Integer>();
```

or

```
Queue<String> myQueue = new LinkedList<String>();
```

[Here's the API for the type of Queues you can instantiate](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html)

[Also see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4626812/how-do-i-instantiate-a-queue-object-in-java)