# Implementing a queue in Java

Tags: java, queue

I am practicing with stacks and queues and have some questions about them (mostly on queues)

How would I implement a queue in my code?

```
package *****;

import java.util.*;

public class stackPractice {

    /**
    * @param args
    */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Stack st = new Stack();
        Queue q = new Queue();

        st.push(100);
        st.push(90);
        st.push(70);

        System.out.println(st);

        //st.pop();

        System.out.println(st.pop());
        System.out.println(st);
        System.out.println(st.peek());

        //value = st.peek();
    }

}
```

I got Stack st to work as a stack, but Queue is giving me problems

on the 2nd Queue after new, there is a red squiggly line that says "Cannot instantiate the type Queue".

```
Queue q = new *Queue*();
```

I am not sure what that means.

---edit---

I know there is no actual code for the queue to do anything yet (enqueue, dequeue, etc...).

Comment: Queue is an interface, you cannot instantiate it.

Comment: Fab, can you restate your comment as an answer?

Comment: You are probably referring to [the built-in Queue interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) instead of your own implementation. Fix your imports.

Answer (score 1):

[`Stack`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html) is a class in Java, but [`Queue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) is an interface, so you can't instantiate it. You'll need to call the constructor of one of its implementing classes.

Answer (score 0):

[`Queue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) is an interface and interfaces cannot be instantiated directly. Use one of its implementations to create an instance of the interface

```
Queue<String> q = new LinkedList<String>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Queue is an interface so you cannot instantiate it but you need to "implement" it.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html

Duplicate here: [How do I instantiate a Queue object in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4626812/how-do-i-instantiate-a-queue-object-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

[Queue is an interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) and can not be instanciated.

You could use a [LinkedList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html). or one of the [listened](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html):

```
   AbstractQueue, ArrayBlockingQueue, ConcurrentLinkedQueue, DelayQueue, LinkedBlockingQueue, LinkedList, PriorityBlockingQueue, PriorityQueue, SynchronousQueue
```