# Issues with imports/library?

Tags: java, jar, queue, stdout, josephus

I am working on an assignment for class:

Josephus problem. In the Josephus problem from antiquity, N people are in dire straits and agree to the following strategy to reduce the population. They arrange themselves in a circle (at positions numbered from 0 to N???1) and proceed around the circle, eliminating every Mth person until only one person is left. Legend has it that Josephus figured out where to sit to avoid being eliminated. Write a Queue client Josephus.java that takes M and N from the command line and prints out the order in which people are eliminated (and thus would show Josephus where to sit in the circle).

My code is as follows :

```
package josephus; 
import java.util.Queue;

public class Josephus  { 

public static void main(String[] args)  {
    int n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]),
        m = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);

    Queue<Integer> q = new Queue<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        q.enqueue(new Integer(i));

    int k = 0;
    while (!q.isEmpty())
    {
        int x = q.dequeue();

        if (++k % m == 0)
            StdOut.print(x + " ");
        else
            q.enqueue(x);
    }
    StdOut.println();
} }
```

When I run it in NetBeans it gives me errors stating that:

Queue is abstract; cannot be instantiated

enqueue: Cannot find symbol

dequeue: Cannot find symbol

StdOut: Cannot find symbol

I thought that by importing the java.util.Queue would make the Queue work and for the StdOut I did download a stdlib.jar to add to the projects library which inculdes StdOut and I thought that would work.

If there is a problem with my code or anything else I need to do, I would really appreciate the help. Also, for reference and to see where I got the stdlib.jar, here is the link for the textbooks website from where this problem comes from : http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/13stacks/ (The Josephus problem is #37 under the "Creative problems section" towards the end.

Comment: Are you familiar with abstract classes?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I instantiate a Queue object in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4626812/how-do-i-instantiate-a-queue-object-in-java)

Comment: Queue<Integer> q = new LinkedList<Integer>(); the problem with your code is that you are trying to instantiate an interface.

Comment: Use [public void println(String x)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println%28java.lang.String%29) for printing

Comment: You may also want to read up on Queues in the Java documentation -- here is the link http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/queue.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Queue` is an interface and cannot be directly instantiated in Java.  You must provide a concrete implementation class, such as `ArrayDeque`.

```
Queue<Integer> q = new ArrayDeque<Integer>();
```

The queue methods `enqueue` and `dequeue` are named differently -- `offer` and `poll`, respectively.  E.g.:

```
q.offer(i);
```

and

```
int x = q.poll();
```

`StdOut` is not a class in Java; use `System.out`, e.g.:

```
System.out.print(x + " ");
```

Comment: Thank you @rgettman. I tried your suggestion and it worked out!